# Password uniqueness: how to test?

Tags: testing, passwords, unique, black-box

There is a password generator that generates passwords based on known rules (a minimum of 10 characters in length, at least 1 of each of uppercase, lowercase, and numeric characters).

No ability to see the source code for this generator. I am just able to generate passwords and automate this process.

How would you test if this generator provides **unique** passwords assuming each password meets rules specified?

Thanks,
Racoon.

Comment: How are you defining "uniqueness"? For instance, if your generator gave you "Password01", then "Password02", then "Password03", etc. Is that a pass?

Comment: Rowland, yes, that is a pass. Uniqueness would mean unique passwords, not matter if they are similar in some way.

Comment: You do I hope realise that there is a limit to password 'uniqueness'? Run the password generator enough times, and I guarantee you that eventually there'll be a collision. I don't need to see the source code to tell you that...

Comment: If you set the limits to "single character" and "use only digits", then you are guaranteed a collision when you generate more than 10 "passwords". I think "randomness" is more important, with say not more than 10% collissions (with your 10 char minimum). Also I would consider "sequential" a fail (see comment by Rowland).

Comment: Hans, Chris, Rowland, thanks! Now, I understand that my question was rather incorrect.

Comment: Why would you use a password generator whose sourcecode you don't know? Most of the password generators I have seen were fatally flawed, which is hard to detect with a blackbox test.

Comment: As a minimal test, call it a billion times. If it contains more than a handful of collisions, it sucks.

Comment: CodesInChaos, honestly I'm not going to use it, but I need it to test. It's a part of a commercial product I'm testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question was incorrect. Every password generator sooner or later provides a value that have been earlier. Better think of randomness than unuqueness.

Answer (score 1):

It does not generate unique passwords - that much I can guarantee you.

If you run this password generator a hundred billion times, what are you expecting to be true of the output? Are you really expecting that every one of those hundred-billion passwords will be different?

If what you're instead trying to ask is whether the passwords will be *reasonably* unique, then you need to define what you mean by 'reasonably unique'.

It also depends on the nature of the rules you specify for generating these passwords. If you specify a maximum length for passwords, then you have by definition set an upper limit on how many unique passwords there even are. Even if you don't, the only way you're getting guaranteed-unique passwords is if said passwords are allowed to grow to lengths that will make them totally impractical to use.